# Issue with the loop foreach php

Tags: php

sorry if my question seems stupid, I'm new to php.
I try to create a loop on my array but the loop returns me only the last value.
I don't understand and I tried everything

```
$categories = array('name' => 'mamals', 'id' => '1');
$categories = array('name' => 'birds','id' => '2');
$categories = array('name' => 'fishs', 'id' => '3');
$categories = array('name' => 'reptiles', 'id' => '4');

$category = $categories;

foreach($category as $key =>$categ){
    echo $categ;
}
```

It return only "reptiles 4" !
Thank you for you answers

Comment: There is no question. It only works as intended. You can delete the first three assignments to `$categories` by the way as you immediately overwrite the variable again. Only the last assignment survives. Compare https://php.net/array

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the variable `categories`, i modified the code by initializing the `categories` with an empty array, then pushing your entries in it.

```
$categories = [];
array_push($categories, array('name' => 'mamals', 'id' => '1'));
array_push($categories, array('name' => 'birds','id' => '2'));
array_push($categories, array('name' => 'fishs', 'id' => '3'));
array_push($categories, array('name' => 'reptiles', 'id' => '4'));

foreach($categories as $key=>$categ){
    echo "ID: " . $categ["id"] . ", NAME: " . $categ["name"];
}
```

Comment: It would help to show the shorthand for this mechanism as well. I don't think anyone would use `array_push` in this sitation.

Answer (score -1):

I response to [shunz19's anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72511367/3536236) where I said:

> It would help to show the shorthand for this mechanism as well. I don't think anyone would use array_push in this sitation.

Here is a more concise solution:

## Cause:

You are *overwriting* your variable - `$categories` - each time you use `=`.
So after line 3 the only value in `$categories` is :

```
categories = array('name' => 'reptiles', 'id' => '4');
```

## Step By Step:

You look like you want to be  *adding* entries to the Categories multidimensional array. Therefore you need to tell PHP to **add** not to **overwrite**, typically with the `[]` indicating the value is to be inserted into a new (incremental) variable key.

```
$categories = array('name' => 'mamals', 'id' => '1');
$categories[] = array('name' => 'birds','id' => '2');
```

This will increment the key index (numeric)  by 1  and set the value of `array` into that key.

It is standard practise to establish numeric arrays and then populate them with this style of referencing.

## But this isn't quite simple...

Because your parent array contains sub-arrays, your `foreach` will give warnings and errors because:

> Warning: Array to string conversion in /home/user/scripts/code.php on line XX

Can you see why?
Yes, because your `foreach`  is only opening the parent array, not the child arrays so the data types within are still arrays, but you want to output them as if they're strings.

How can you do this? With a fun little function called [`print_r()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php).

## Concise Solution and Fix:

```
$categories = []; // Establish the var type is an array.
$categories[] = array('name' => 'mamals', 'id' => '1'); // Add to the array.
$categories[] = array('name' => 'birds','id' => '2'); // add more,... 
$categories[] = array('name' => 'fishs', 'id' => '3');
$categories[] = array('name' => 'reptiles', 'id' => '4');

$category = $categories;

foreach($category as $key =>$categ){
     print_r($categ);
}
```

## Output:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [name] => mamals
>     [id] => 1
> )
> Array
> (
>     [name] => birds
>     [id] => 2
> )
> Array
> (
>     [name] => fishs
>     [id] => 3
> )
> Array
> (
>     [name] => reptiles
>     [id] => 4
> )
> ```

## Code Example:

You can alternatively just access the array names from the froeach such as:

```
foreach($category as $key =>$categ){
     print $categ['name']."\n"; // will list each name starting at the lowest array key. 
}
```

[See my test code here](https://onlinephp.io/c/e98f3).

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer you are very clear and i get it :)

Comment: @Ascaris29 that's great. Please feel free to tick the answer and +1 the Up arrow next to the answer. Thanks `:-)`